# Make route endpoint respond with different content based on user authentication

Tags: node.js, express

Say that I am building a simple web app with a REST back-end where users have their own page with user information.

What I would like to achieve is, if an unauthenticated user makes a request to

*www.mywebapp.com/api/user/john*

they would be provided with limited information (only age and email for example). But if the users logs in, and makes the same request, the server will also respond with more information (like personal preferences and such).

I am thinking that maybe the middleware that validates the users token, passes on permission on the request (req.role = guest or req.role = user). Then in the user/:name endpoint it would check the role and respond with different content.

The other option would be to make a new route endpoint for authenticated users, and then check which one to call on the client side.

What is best practice here?

Comment: Go for the middleware one. A lot of widely used authentication modules (like [passportjs](http://passportjs.org)) use this pattern.

Comment: I use passport for user authentication. To check if the user is logged in I check if req.session.passport.user exists. If it does exist I then use that variable to query the database to see what type of user the logged in user is (admin, regular, etc). I serve the appropriate content depending on what user type is returned from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing:

```
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/profile', authenticate, hasRole("Admin", true), controller.showProfileAdmin);
router.get('/profile', hasRole("User", true), controller.showProfileUser);
// will not call next('route') if Guest requirements is not met
router.get('/profile', hasRole("Guest"), controller.showProfile); 

// hasRole() returns a middleware function that checks if user meets role requirement.
// If nextRoute is true, the function calls next('route'). If nextRoute is false
// or undefined, the function responds with a 403
function hasRole(roleRequired, nextRoute) {

    return (req, res, next) => {
        // Just checking so that the user has authority for this role.
        if (config.userRoles.indexOf(req.user.role) >= config.userRoles.indexOf(roleRequired)) {
            return next();
        //else client is not authorized
        } else {
            // If nextRoute is true, continue to the next route.
            if(nextRoute){
                return next('route');
            //Else respond with a forbidden status.
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(403);
            }
        }
    }
}
```